# Get response in XML in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have created a client that consumes SOAP services, and one of these services supports a parameter called "enpoint_response", which is where it will send the response when the client consumes the service. My idea is that those answers, in XML format, reach a Flask server, and are saved in an XML file ... But it is the first time I use Flask, and I have been reading for 3 hours but I get lost, it would be possible to do this What do I comment? If so, how?

This is the client that consumes the SOAP services:

```
from suds.sax.text import Raw
import ssl
from suds.client import Client
import logging
import pathlib
from os.path import abspath

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, handlers=[logging.FileHandler(
    filename=pathlib.Path(abspath("logs/consume.log")), mode="w"), logging.StreamHandler()])


def wsdl_uri(relative_path):
    return pathlib.Path(abspath(f"{relative_path}")).as_uri()


ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

url = wsdl_uri("resources/SOAP/info.wsdl")

client = Client(url)

order = "4433221"
id_s = "id123"
version = "01.00.00"
endpoint_response = "http://localhost:5000/save_response"

pet = client.factory.create("pet")

in_data_dict = {
    "p1": "AAA",
    "p2": "BBB",
    "p3": "CCC",
    "p4": "DDD",
}

in_data = ""

for key, value in in_data_dict.items():
    in_data += f"<{key}>{value}</{key}>"

p = Raw(
    f"""<datos_entrada><dato_entrada>{in_data}</dato_entrada></datos_entrada>"""
)

resp = pet.service.myService(
    order, id_s, version, endpoint_response, p)
```

And this is the XML that the service returns, which I want to be received by the Flask server and saved in a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:local xmlns:ns2="uri">
    <response>
        <name>OutputParameters</name>
        <valueType>Map</valueType>
        <mapValue>
            <key>ho_key</key>
            <value>ho#1234567890#ERROR: ERROR 123</value>
        </mapValue>
        <mapValue>
            <key>oh_result</key>
            <value>[#list_in_params#
#p1=AAA#
#p2=BBB#
#p3=CCC#
#p4=DDD#]
ho#1234567890#ERROR: FAIL
FAIL 123: IN X: &lt;XX\ZZZZZ&gt; and TEST: &lt;T-1&gt;</value>
        </mapValue>
    </response>
</ns2:local>
```

The only unknown I have is how to deal with that response XML in Flask ...

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be a soap endpoint per se? If not, I would just try to create a REST service (which is pretty easy in https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which accepts plan text to where XML is sent. 
If you need proper SOAP response you could check past Flask and go for Zeep (no experience though).

Comment: I send a request to a soap endpoint, but the response is an XML. In my Flask server I do not receive anything, not even that from another site an attempt has been made to make a POST, GET, etc ... Does that mean that the Web Service to which I send the request is not responding to the Flask server, right? Or at least nothing is reaching it ... Because at least it would arrive that a POST has been made, right?

Comment: If you don't see anything at all appear in your Flask server than that would be the first thing to look into. It would depend on the type of call you are making and the endpoint you are calling. POST/PUT/GET etc. are usually verbs belonging to a REST or simple HTTP endpoint. A soap endpoint is usually about different data (that is, SOAP protocol and XML). Using Zeep you should be able to setup a server for that as well. There is a way to receive SOAP messages using REST endpoints but I never tried it myself.

Comment: Yes, I have the Flask server listening on http://myIp:5000 and I have created a path in /receiver. When I send the SOAP request with the client, I put http://myIp:5000/receiver as the response endpoint. Something should get to the server, right? That a POST, a GET or something has been done ... I'm going to investigate if with zeep I can do something ... Although I think nothing is coming :(

Comment: Good luck with that. Debugging using non-soap interfaces to check if the endpoint can receive at least something would be a nice start. That is, just use something like postman or soapui to call your endpoint and check its response. If you can't reach it that way, you need to alter flask. I'm afraid I cant help you otherwise.